# Container going outside the screen in narrow screen phones using Next js and react native web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, react-native-web

I have been building a web application using Next.js and React Native Web, the parent container is clearly fitting in desktop and in some phones but is going outside the screen for some phones that has a narrower screen like galaxy s5, moto G4, I am adding screenshots for better understanding below.

desktop view
[image]

mobile view(where the container is fitting)

[image]

mobile view (where the container is going outside the screen)

[image]

Parent container styles added:

```
 <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    maxWidth: "600px",
    paddingBottom: 100}>
       <Text>something....</Text>
</View>
</View>
```

Am using Next.js for the first time and am unable to understand how to fix this issue, if anyone could help me out here it would be great.

Comment: Do you have any additional css anywhere? Because it looks like you have padding or margin to the right of the view so its pushes it to the left!

Comment: This is because you have set `maxWidth: "600px",`. You should remove it. To make this page more responsive you should set `flex-direction` of mobile number and city inputs container to as `column` when the screen is lesser than `600px`.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera even if I remove maxwidth it is behaving the same, so I dont think it is related to maxwidth,but if you could give some code reference, would like to try

Comment: no, I have nowhere added padding or margin @jonas

Comment: Is this resolved?